# How to check if time period is overlapping another time period in java using LocaDateTime?

Tags: java

I need to check if time period overlaps another time, why I always get false if even I know that this times won't overlaps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LocalDateTime dateToAdd = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-02-10T12:30");

    LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-02-10T10:00");
    LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-02-10T11:00");
    LocalDateTime date3 = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-02-10T14:00");
    LocalDateTime date4 = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-02-10T17:00");
    LocalDateTime date5 = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-02-10T19:00");

    List<LocalDateTime> dates = List.of(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5);

    boolean b = dates.stream()
            .allMatch(dateTime -> isOverlapping(dateTime, dateTime.plusHours(1), dateToAdd, dateToAdd.plusHours(1)));

    System.out.println(b);

}

public static boolean isOverlapping(LocalDateTime start1, LocalDateTime end1, LocalDateTime start2, LocalDateTime end2) {
    return start1.isBefore(end2) && start2.isBefore(end1);
}
```

Comment: "_why I always get false if even I know that this times won't overlaps._" - So you are getting the result you are expecting? Or am I reading this wrong? Can you explain what you are expecting? None of these will "overlap" since they are all more than 1h apart and you check it in a 1h time frame.

Comment: I need to expect true that allMatch should return true because result of is overlapping is always false so allMatch result is always the same so should return boolean b true

Comment: I think you misunderstand the use of `allMatch()`. "_Returns whether all elements of this stream match the provided predicate._" - This is not the case, since none of your elements are overlapping. You could use `noneMatch()` instead (or `anyMatch()` depending on the use case), if I understand you correctly. Please specify what should happen if a) none overlap, b) one overlaps c) all overlap.

Comment: a) return true b) return false c) return false

Comment: Then use `noneMatch()` instead of `allMatch()`.